# cannot run gdb on mac's terminal even after codesign

Tags: macos, gdb

I'm trying to install gdb on my Mac. I downloaded it with brew and code signed it according to the instructions on https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin
However, when I run gdb in the terminal, it still doesn't work and output the following error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gdb
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Does anyone know what it means? My Mac version is 10.11.5, by the way

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue on macOS 10.11.6, I'm guessing (and this is just speculation; I don't actually know how Homebrew works) that Homebrew installed a pre-compiled version of `gdb` which depended on a library that existed on the machine it was compiled with, but did not exist on my machine.

At any rate, I was able to get a working version of `gdb` by downloading & unzipping version `7.12` (`8.1` failed to compile on my machine) from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.12.tar.gz, then compiling & installing with (IIRC) the commands:

- `./configure`
- `make`
- `sudo make install`

I blogged about this and the subsequent steps (getting the executable code-signed so that macOS would allow it to debug other processes, etc) here: http://prust.github.io/posts/2018-02-24-interactively-debugging-c-in-sublime-text-3.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It almost works for me, but the make quits with 
 location.c: In function ‘event_location* string_to_explicit_location(const char**, const language_defn*, int’:
location.c:527:19: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
       || *argp == '\0'
                   ^~~~
make[2]: *** [location.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-gdb] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Lee: It looks like you can backport this fix to v7.12 so that it will compile with a recent gcc: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20653 (I'm not sure why it succeeded for me, perhaps I have an older version of gcc)

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem too. And I find solution in https://qiita.com/yoshixj/items/698d94337ca447e9b9de
Since we don't have `/usr/local/opt/mpfr/lib/libmpfr.6.dylib`
we can simply install it. Use this command:

```
brew install gawk

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when running gdb after installing it from Homebrew (gdb v8.1) on a Mac OS X El Capitan v10.11.6. However, installing it via Homebrew using its Python binary solved the issue:

```
brew install gdb --with-python
```

Beaware that this may take some time, since you'd be compiling gdb from scratch. After it's done, you still need to create a certificate and codesign gdb.